# Is there any way I can make sure only one scrollView instance has scrollsToTop == YES?

Tags: ios, objective-c

The app I'm currently working on has multiple `UITableView`/`UIScrollView` instance at the same time in multiple different scenes.

When multiple instances has `scrollsToTop == YES`, only one instance actually scrolls to top when status bar is tapped.

I'm looking for the **easiest solution** to make sure only one instance (most recent one) of scroll view has `scrollsToTop == YES`.

I came up with a solution using **method swizzling** which I'm **not sure** if it's the **best solution**. I want to know any other way to solve this problem or any kind of suggestions.

Here is my solution:

1. Create `UIScrollView`'s category add method `mySetScroolsToTop:`

   ```
   -(void)mySetScrollsToTop:(BOOL)scrollsToTop{
       [self mySetScrollsToTop:scrollsToTop];

       if(scrollsToTop){
           [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
               postNotificationName:SetScrollsToTopNotification object:self];  
       }

   }

   -(void)scrollsToTopIsSet:(NSNotification *)notification{

       if(notification.object != self){
           [self mySetScrollsToTop:NO];
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create `UIViewController`'s category with following methods

   ```
   -(void)myViewDidLoad{

    self findScrollViewAndObserveScrollToTopNotification:self.view];

    [self myViewDidLoad];

   }


   -(void)findScrollViewAndObserveScrollToTopNotification:(UIView *)view{

    for(UIView* v in view.subviews){

     if([v isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]){

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:v
                                                selector:@selector(scrollsToTopIsSet:)
                                                    name:kSetScrollsToTopNotification
                                                  object:nil];
     }

    [self findScrollViewAndObserveScrollToTopNotification:v];

    }
   }

   -(void)myDealloc{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [self myDealloc];

   }
   ```
3. swap `mySetScrollsToTop`, `myViewDidLoad`, and `myDealloc` with original ones using **method swizzling**.

**Edit:**

Sorry, if my question wasn't clear.

Each `viewcontroller` has multiple `tableViews` and they are switched by user for example with segmented control. When a `tableView`/`scrollView` is selected, I want to set its `scrollToTop = YES` and want to make sure all other `scrollView`'s `scrollsToTop` is set to NO.

The app I'm working on has left menu bar like Facebook app, which has a `UITableView` inside and also a tab bar which each tab contains a `UITableView` which is displayed over the menu `UITableView`. On right pane, there are also `UITableView`s which can be selected and switched with segmented controller.
I want to make sure only one table view is active to `scrollsToTop`.

**Edit2:**

I printed out window's subview and did not contain my views:

```
2013-05-16 10:44:01.416  UIView
2013-05-16 10:44:01.417  UILayoutContainerView
2013-05-16 10:44:01.417  UINavigationTransitionView
2013-05-16 10:44:01.417  UIView
2013-05-16 10:44:01.417  UILayoutContainerView
2013-05-16 10:44:01.417  UINavigationTransitionView
2013-05-16 10:44:01.417  UINavigationBar
2013-05-16 10:44:01.417  _UINavigationBarBackground
2013-05-16 10:44:01.417  UIImageView
2013-05-16 10:44:01.418   UIButton
2013-05-16 10:44:01.418  UIImageView
2013-05-16 10:44:01.418  UIImageView
```

**Edit3:**
I implemented swizzling and it works. However, I'm still accepting any better solution.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`scrollsToTop` defaults to `YES` for all scroll views.

Make your view controller the delegate for all of your scroll views and then implement this:

```
- (BOOL)scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return (scrollView == <the only scroll view you want to scroll to the top>);
}
```

When the top bar is tapped, `scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:` will be called and you should return YES for the scroll view you want to scroll.

**Edit for updated question:**

This will do what you're asking for.

```
// Set `scrollsToTop` to false for every scroll view of every view controller
for (UIViewController *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
    for (id obj in controller.view.subviews)
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
            ((UIScrollView*)obj).scrollsToTop = NO;

// Set `scrollsToTop` to true for whichever scroll view is currently visible
activeScrollView.scrollsToTop = YES;
```

Comment: Sorry I think my question was confusing. I edit my question. Thanks!

Comment: @kazuochi I updated my answer to address your updated question.

Comment: I have to take care of all the tableView which is not necessary in the same viewController. For example, I have left menu bar which contains tableView. when the left menu table is active to scrollsToTop and hidden under the right pane, any of tableView in the right pane does not scrolls up when status bar is tapped. To solve this, I have to disable leftMenu bar's scrollsToTop and enable right pane's active tableView when left pane is closed. I'm trying to resolve this issue without taking care of all possible cases. Thanks anyway!

Comment: A scroll view which is in a view controller which is not the current view controller should not scroll to the top when the top bar is tapped, even if `scrollsToTop == YES`.

Comment: But tableviews on right pane does not scrolls up without disabling the hidden tableView's scrollsToTop on the left pane.

Comment: @kazuochi Edited again to handle all view controllers in your app's navigation controller.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your help.

Comment: @kazuochi Please mark this post as the accepted answer by clicking the checkmark next to it if it adequately solved your problem.

Comment: It's my problem that I'm not able to explain the issue I have clearer, but I don't think you understand exact issue I have. The parent controller is not a navigation controller and I do not want the child controllers to have reference to parent controller. Thanks!

Comment: The child controllers have **no reference** to the parent controllers, nor the other way around.  All the method does is use the **navigation controller** which is present in most, if not all, iOS applications.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following methods:

```
- (void) disableScrollToTopExceptScrollView:(UIScrollView*) scrollView
{
    [self internalDisableScrollViewsExceptScrollView:scrollView rootView:self.window];
}

- (void) internalDisableScrollViewsExceptScrollView:(UIScrollView*) scrollView rootView:(UIView*) root
{
    NSArray* subviews = root.subviews;
    for(UIView* view in subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
        {
           if(view==scrollView)
           {
               [(UIScrollView*)view setScrollsToTop:YES];
           }
            else
            {
                [(UIScrollView*)view setScrollsToTop:NO];
            }
        }
        [self internalDisableScrollViewsExceptScrollView:scrollView rootView:view];
    }
}
```

E.g. implement them in the AppDelegate class, and call from any point in your app - this will disable all the scrollviews in app's view hierarchy except the one you passed.

Comment: I printed out all subview of the UIWindow, however it did not have my views.

Comment: I printed subview of UIViews but I couldn't find any there as well. Thanks!

Comment: try to call this method every time you switch your scrollviews - pass active scroll view as one that should stay active and your app's window as root view

Comment: Hi, window's subview does not contain any of my views. I confirmed by using a method which recursively dig into subviews and print the subview's class name out. The output is in Edit2. Thanks!